# Olap/multi dimensional reporting, WPF client, agnostic data?

Tags: sql-server, wpf, oracle, mdx, olap

Can anyone give me general guidelines on how to approach multi dimensional reporting where I'd like to support at the very least cube generated from Oracle and SQL Server databases. I can imagine GemFire or Coherence being in the mix too.

I'm a little unsure where to start. If I work entirely in the Microsoft ecosystem I'm fine with SQL Server Analysis services, reporting services, MDX. Introduce the other data sources and I'm lost.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following vendors can all do what you need:

SAP Business Objects
IBM Cognos
Microstrategy
Actuate

Oracle and Microsoft will both work great with only ONE of your datasources.

Try looking under keywords "Business Intelligence" for Gartner group papers and other useful whitepapers from sources like InformationWeek.  There are MANY vendors in this space, I encourage you to do a very deep slice prototype, because they all look great in demo, but might not work for you.

Also, the CUBE you mention (OLAP) is truly a performance booster.  But you can do "multi-dimensional reporting" without Cubes.  Maybe slower, but less intimidating and definitely less expensive.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding prices you've a bunch of free OLAP servers available, depending on your needs all of them will be fine. Just look for the ones following XMLA/MDX standard.

Amongst them vou've the classical [Mondrian](http://mondrian.pentaho.com/) (ROLAP) and one new coming [icCube](http://www.iccube.com/) (MOLAP).

Comment: Very interesting. I'm looking at icCube now.